# cURL receives "encoded" response from nginx server

Tags: javascript, python, curl

I'm doing a scrape on a platform, and I'm using the cURL method to get the direct data, but I always get an "encoded" response, which I thought was compressed (but isn't), and now I believe the answer is in some format I don't know. Even intercepting the platform, it ALSO receives the same "encoded" response without using cURL. Here is a snippet of the answer obtained, as it was too big:

```
SA÷1¬~AA÷dYAcKvjJ¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷3.2¬YA÷2.5¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.4¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷1¬XC÷2.25¬YC÷2.6¬MG÷1¬~AA÷UR4xGotq¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷4.5¬YA÷4.5¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.75¬YB÷3.75¬MG÷1¬XC÷1.66¬YC÷1.66¬MG÷1¬~AA÷t28tF5ek¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷6.5¬YA÷5.75¬MG÷1¬XB÷4.33¬YB÷4.33¬MG÷1¬XC÷1.4¬YC÷1.44¬MG÷1¬~AA÷OQcoEPAe¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷2.75¬YA÷2.75¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.5¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷1¬XC÷2.3¬YC÷2.25¬MG÷1¬~AA÷zcu2Zz9N¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷1.22¬YA÷1.33¬MG÷1¬XB÷5.75¬YB÷5¬MG÷1¬XC÷15¬YC÷9¬MG÷1¬~AA÷4ScQTEWp¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷4¬YA÷3.5¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.75¬YB÷3.6¬MG÷1¬XC÷1.85¬YC÷2¬MG÷1¬~AA÷hlvLkdg4¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷2.62¬YA÷2.37¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.3¬YB÷3.5¬MG÷1¬XC÷2.6¬YC÷2.8¬MG÷1¬~AA÷OpbuAPxn¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷1.66¬YA÷1.5¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.6¬YB÷4¬MG÷1¬XC÷4.2¬YC÷5¬MG÷1¬~AA÷WA1m837b¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷1.16¬YA÷1.14¬MG÷1¬XB÷7.5¬YB÷6.5¬MG÷1¬XC÷17¬YC÷15¬MG÷1¬~AA÷pQ3WaXNE¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷1.7¬YA÷1.9¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.4¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷1¬XC÷4.75¬YC÷3.6¬MG÷1¬~AA÷xMRar5hs¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷3.6¬YA÷3.2¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.1¬YB÷3¬MG÷1¬XC÷2.1¬YC÷2.25¬MG÷1¬~AA÷YmL8tqNg¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷1.16¬YA÷1.16¬MG÷1¬XB÷7¬YB÷7¬MG÷1¬XC÷11¬YC÷11¬MG÷1¬~AA÷6FYFvNi6¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷2.15¬YA÷2.2¬MG÷1¬XB÷3¬YB÷3.1¬MG÷1¬XC÷3.25¬YC÷3.1¬MG÷1¬~AA÷GWbtT9bp¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷2.15¬YA÷2.3¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.25¬YB÷3.25¬MG÷1¬XC÷3¬YC÷2.75¬MG÷1¬~AA÷fNcpSTDj¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷2.3¬YA÷2.05¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.4¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷1¬XC÷2.7¬YC÷3.1¬MG÷1¬~AA÷dSyTjDji¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷7.5¬YA÷7.5¬MG÷1¬XB÷4¬YB÷4.2¬MG÷1¬XC÷1.36¬YC÷1.36¬MG÷1¬~AA÷fDfWkX5c¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷1.83¬YA÷1.83¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.5¬YB÷3.6¬MG÷1¬XC÷3.75¬YC÷3.6¬MG÷1¬~AA÷lzfzkiL3¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷3¬YA÷2.15¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.3¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷1¬XC÷2.15¬YC÷2.9¬MG÷1¬~AA÷boycy2Rp¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷2.25¬YA÷1.8¬MG÷1¬XB÷2.8¬YB÷3.2¬MG÷1¬XC÷3.5¬YC÷4.5¬MG÷1¬~AA÷0jFu0o4o¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷1.9¬YA÷1.9¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.6¬YB÷3.6¬MG÷1¬XC÷3.5¬YC÷3.4¬MG÷1¬~AA÷6mImbPYc¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷3.5¬YA÷2.7¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.1¬YB÷3.1¬MG÷1¬XC÷2.05¬YC÷2.5¬MG÷1¬~AA÷pvHicql4¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷1.9¬YA÷1.9¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.25¬YB÷3.25¬MG÷1¬XC÷3.8¬YC÷3.75¬MG÷1¬~AA÷6arlN0r7¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷4.75¬YA÷2.5¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.6¬YB÷3.2¬MG÷1¬XC÷1.75¬YC÷2.8¬MG÷1¬~AA÷pjshMKcD¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷1.9¬YA÷1.8¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.2¬YB÷3.7¬MG÷1¬XC÷4.75¬YC÷4.2¬MG÷1¬~AA÷bXm4Ty5t¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷1.85¬YA÷2.05¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.25¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷1¬XC÷4.75¬YC÷3.5¬MG÷1¬~AA÷hfm8SeKn¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷1.28¬YA÷1.25¬MG÷1¬XB÷5.5¬YB÷5.5¬MG÷1¬XC÷12¬YC÷12¬MG÷1¬~AA÷6ciCRFZh¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷2.3¬YA÷2.7¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.1¬YB÷3.2¬MG÷1¬XC÷3.4¬YC÷2.6¬MG÷1¬~AA÷rkHPHEPA¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷3.2¬YA÷3¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.4¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷1¬XC÷2¬YC÷2.1¬MG÷1¬~AA÷MuGTGYvH¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷3.6¬YA÷3.6¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.6¬YB÷3.6¬MG÷1¬XC÷1.83¬YC÷1.83¬MG÷1¬~AA÷G2FXFhfN¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷1.45¬YA÷1.5¬MG÷1¬XB÷4¬YB÷4¬MG÷1¬XC÷6¬YC÷5.5¬MG÷1¬~AA÷U5JyFC9T¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷3.4¬YA÷3.2¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.5¬YB÷3.5¬MG÷1¬XC÷1.9¬YC÷2¬MG÷1¬~AA÷zmd4AWHp¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷1.5¬YA÷1.6¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.8¬YB÷3.75¬MG÷1¬XC÷6¬YC÷5¬MG÷1¬~AA÷tCHG4Oda¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷1.4¬YA÷1.4¬MG÷1¬XB÷4.5¬YB÷4.5¬MG÷1¬XC÷8.5¬YC÷8¬MG÷1¬XX÷XA|XB|XC¬~AA÷SACWhcAK¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷2.15¬YA÷2.1¬MG÷1¬XB÷3.6¬YB÷3.5¬MG÷1¬XC÷3.1¬YC÷3.25¬MG÷1¬~AA÷61BzhHPQ¬AY÷1¬ODA÷16¬XA÷¬XB÷3.56¬YB÷3.3¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.66¬YC÷4.04¬MG÷0¬~AA÷0jZmsPsk¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.1¬YA÷2.89¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.62¬YB÷3.44¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.04¬YC÷2.22¬MG÷0¬~AA÷485JtcDK¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.09¬YA÷2.05¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.08¬YB÷3.2¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.6¬YC÷3.62¬MG÷0¬~AA÷zidkyyyr¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.45¬YA÷2.27¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.1¬YB÷3.24¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.8¬YC÷3.07¬MG÷0¬~AA÷d6pbZE5f¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.74¬YA÷1.74¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.52¬YB÷3.6¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.5¬YC÷4.22¬MG÷0¬~AA÷UyOg9Ptl¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.23¬YA÷1.23¬MG÷0¬XB÷5.35¬YB÷5.5¬MG÷0¬XC÷12.5¬YC÷12.5¬MG÷0¬~AA÷8SMc8qdf¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.36¬YA÷2.4¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.4¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.65¬YC÷2.7¬MG÷0¬~AA÷GhQ56NQ6¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.61¬YA÷1.55¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.58¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷0¬XC÷5.55¬YC÷6.6¬MG÷0¬~AA÷bHFA5stD¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.44¬YA÷2.37¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.97¬YB÷3.15¬MG÷0¬XC÷3¬YC÷2.97¬MG÷0¬~AA÷d2YD41eJ¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷4.3¬YA÷4.18¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.54¬YB÷3.7¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.77¬YC÷1.77¬MG÷0¬~AA÷A5MeTpYJ¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.59¬YA÷1.69¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.86¬YB÷3.9¬MG÷0¬XC÷5.2¬YC÷4.38¬MG÷0¬~AA÷fHlAAsJt¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.07¬YA÷2.07¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.05¬YB÷3.05¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.8¬YC÷3.8¬MG÷0¬~AA÷p6sN7u3a¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.11¬YA÷2.17¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.97¬YB÷3.05¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.7¬YC÷3.5¬MG÷0¬~AA÷b9oR6aI5¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.47¬YA÷2.47¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.94¬YB÷3.05¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.98¬YC÷2.97¬MG÷0¬~AA÷hWpV5JXB¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷5.65¬YA÷4.68¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.72¬YB÷3.64¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.57¬YC÷1.69¬MG÷0¬~AA÷WMqZ4wmI¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.17¬YA÷3.15¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.16¬YB÷3.3¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.23¬YC÷2.12¬MG÷0¬~AA÷bqGV3c2O¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.22¬YA÷3.36¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.02¬YB÷3.1¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.27¬YC÷2.2¬MG÷0¬~AA÷CzYNMkUn¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.44¬YA÷2.37¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.06¬YB÷3.24¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.91¬YC÷2.92¬MG÷0¬~AA÷fJTrIRrI¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.97¬YA÷1.94¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.2¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.84¬YC÷3.76¬MG÷0¬~AA÷4pcVgMQD¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.33¬YA÷2.27¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.15¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.04¬YC÷3.07¬MG÷0¬~AA÷08USgVqc¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.99¬YA÷1.85¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.28¬YB÷3.24¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.72¬YC÷3.84¬MG÷0¬~AA÷f7Nyh9E9¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.15¬YA÷2.12¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.16¬YB÷3.1¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.4¬YC÷3.26¬MG÷0¬~AA÷YcMuiTTF¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.7¬YA÷1.69¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.38¬YB÷2.9¬MG÷0¬XC÷5.25¬YC÷6.1¬MG÷0¬~AA÷n52GpR6q¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷5.4¬YA÷6.1¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.8¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.59¬YC÷1.55¬MG÷0¬~AA÷fV5Or5yd¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.52¬YA÷2.27¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.12¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.74¬YC÷3.07¬MG÷0¬~AA÷6BdGGmme¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.44¬YA÷3.05¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.13¬YB÷3.2¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.15¬YC÷2.22¬MG÷0¬~AA÷0YeKF721¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.32¬YA÷3.32¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.05¬YB÷3.24¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.24¬YC÷2.02¬MG÷0¬~AA÷EoR1Aorj¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.54¬YA÷1.62¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.2¬YB÷4.6¬MG÷0¬XC÷5.2¬YC÷4.16¬MG÷0¬~AA÷xpQsB8AP¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.32¬YA÷2.32¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.52¬YB÷3.6¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.74¬YC÷2.72¬MG÷0¬~AA÷vgC96SIt¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.72¬YA÷3.8¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.72¬YB÷3.7¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.84¬YC÷1.85¬MG÷0¬~AA÷CCVW3zdT¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.12¬YA÷1.21¬MG÷0¬XB÷8.1¬YB÷6.2¬MG÷0¬XC÷17¬YC÷11.5¬MG÷0¬~AA÷WdC3bEJj¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.07¬YA÷2.82¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.58¬YB÷3.3¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.19¬YC÷2.42¬MG÷0¬~AA÷KECb6ujS¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷4.44¬YA÷3.58¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.92¬YB÷4.5¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.67¬YC÷1.74¬MG÷0¬~AA÷fcGDx2aC¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷4¬YA÷4¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.5¬YB÷4.5¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.62¬YC÷1.62¬MG÷0¬~AA÷xM5IyMEI¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷5.05¬YA÷3.38¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.26¬YB÷4.1¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.53¬YC÷1.87¬MG÷0¬~AA÷4SZQLXzf¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.81¬YA÷2.28¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.22¬YB÷3.74¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.34¬YC÷2.65¬MG÷0¬~AA÷ChZUKij0¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.28¬YA÷1.54¬MG÷0¬XB÷5.9¬YB÷4.7¬MG÷0¬XC÷7.1¬YC÷4.64¬MG÷0¬~AA÷Y7NwJVKC¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.62¬YA÷1.66¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.6¬YB÷4.4¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.9¬YC÷4.06¬MG÷0¬~AA÷zBbMp5et¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.74¬YA÷2.27¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.3¬YB÷2.85¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.88¬YC÷3.52¬MG÷0¬~AA÷dnp7OEHi¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.34¬YA÷1.31¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.9¬YB÷4.74¬MG÷0¬XC÷7.6¬YC÷7.8¬MG÷0¬~AA÷vBZBNYWc¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.17¬YA÷2.15¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.09¬YB÷3.05¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.38¬YC÷3.52¬MG÷0¬~AA÷jowGMhn4¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.14¬YA÷2.07¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.32¬YB÷3.2¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.2¬YC÷3.56¬MG÷0¬~AA÷p8xKLC1A¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.05¬YA÷3.46¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.94¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.37¬YC÷2.12¬MG÷0¬~AA÷ObyOKWGG¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.28¬YA÷2.32¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.1¬YB÷2.9¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.14¬YC÷3.32¬MG÷0¬~AA÷v9fh34oq¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.97¬YA÷3.05¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.22¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.3¬YC÷2.32¬MG÷0¬~AA÷CMh01rGe¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.08¬YA÷2.92¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.16¬YB÷3.05¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.27¬YC÷2.47¬MG÷0¬~AA÷QPd402V1¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.51¬YA÷1.57¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.98¬YB÷3.9¬MG÷0¬XC÷6¬YC÷5.65¬MG÷0¬~AA÷zN2snX3G¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.93¬YA÷1.82¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.44¬YB÷3.3¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.68¬YC÷4.06¬MG÷0¬~AA÷lQ6ooiJM¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.02¬YA÷1.97¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.22¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.48¬YC÷3.36¬MG÷0¬~AA÷rm6kpBYS¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.62¬YA÷1.64¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.54¬YB÷3.5¬MG÷0¬XC÷5.2¬YC÷5.1¬MG÷0¬~AA÷pdhHuVtp¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷18¬YA÷15¬MG÷0¬XB÷5.45¬YB÷6¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.17¬YC÷1.14¬MG÷0¬~AA÷2XnMvkdj¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.59¬YA÷1.55¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.9¬YB÷4¬MG÷0¬XC÷5.1¬YC÷5¬MG÷0¬~AA÷tOoQw9Bd¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.45¬YA÷1.37¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.22¬YB÷4.32¬MG÷0¬XC÷6.4¬YC÷7.2¬MG÷0¬~AA÷fRZ72hlc¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.87¬YA÷1.72¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.4¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.84¬YC÷4.56¬MG÷0¬~AA÷lQSG0WI9¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.61¬YA÷1.69¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.04¬YB÷4¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.72¬YC÷3.86¬MG÷0¬~AA÷S2pgYEl9¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.93¬YA÷2.27¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.11¬YB÷2.8¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.96¬YC÷3.36¬MG÷0¬~AA÷t6lcXY3F¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.63¬YA÷1.62¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.52¬YB÷3.6¬MG÷0¬XC÷5.15¬YC÷5¬MG÷0¬~AA÷M32RF6Ys¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.76¬YA÷2.12¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.42¬YB÷2.9¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.36¬YC÷3.56¬MG÷0¬~AA÷0f1VEQml¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.35¬YA÷1.37¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.6¬YB÷4.32¬MG÷0¬XC÷7.6¬YC÷6.35¬MG÷0¬~AA÷fVFYDp3f¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.02¬YA÷2.2¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.99¬YB÷2.95¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.98¬YC÷3.56¬MG÷0¬~AA÷YLExD4I0¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.45¬YA÷2.6¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.61¬YB÷2.8¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.96¬YC÷2.75¬MG÷0¬~AA÷Gp4sCOX6¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.86¬YA÷1.85¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.2¬YB÷3.3¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.16¬YC÷4.04¬MG÷0¬~AA÷Um8oBrmD¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.16¬YA÷2.62¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.07¬YB÷2.8¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.28¬YC÷2.62¬MG÷0¬~AA÷ridTZRPD¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.63¬YA÷1.62¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.5¬YB÷3.5¬MG÷0¬XC÷5.15¬YC÷5.05¬MG÷0¬~AA÷rcTxRzy6¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.32¬YA÷2.37¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.02¬YB÷2.8¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.16¬YC÷3.36¬MG÷0¬~AA÷MmStQfjC¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.34¬YA÷2.42¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.92¬YB÷2.8¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.08¬YC÷3.06¬MG÷0¬~AA÷GARpPE5I¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.78¬YA÷1.84¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.38¬YB÷3.24¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.5¬YC÷4.4¬MG÷0¬~AA÷SpVlOYKO¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.66¬YA÷2.32¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.02¬YB÷2.8¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.63¬YC÷3.18¬MG÷0¬~AA÷Uk9XnIcP¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.4¬YA÷1.45¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.28¬YB÷4¬MG÷0¬XC÷7.5¬YC÷6.2¬MG÷0¬~AA÷Wbearx6t¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.74¬YA÷2.8¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.05¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.54¬YC÷2.55¬MG÷0¬~AA÷0Ya3sdLn¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.96¬YA÷1.93¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.06¬YB÷3.1¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.96¬YC÷4.04¬MG÷0¬~AA÷vPb7tGzg¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷5.05¬YA÷5.05¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.42¬YB÷3.3¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.66¬YC÷1.69¬MG÷0¬~AA÷MmlCuzja¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.92¬YA÷1.93¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.32¬YB÷3.1¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.86¬YC÷3.82¬MG÷0¬~AA÷2mDG5icT¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.46¬YA÷3.58¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.18¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.05¬YC÷2.02¬MG÷0¬~AA÷KSar1B5p¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷48¬YA÷33¬MG÷0¬XB÷12.5¬YB÷8¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.02¬YC÷1.07¬MG÷0¬~AA÷zyrVOEci¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.74¬YA÷3.86¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.2¬YB÷3.1¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.96¬YC÷1.93¬MG÷0¬~AA÷ERtZNYCc¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.93¬YA÷1.92¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.36¬YB÷3.34¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.76¬YC÷3.86¬MG÷0¬~AA÷8ltwNhS3¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷28¬YA÷16¬MG÷0¬XB÷10.5¬YB÷7¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.05¬YC÷1.11¬MG÷0¬~AA÷KOqsMCsA¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷4.36¬YA÷3.88¬MG÷0¬XB÷3¬YB÷2.7¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.9¬YC÷2.12¬MG÷0¬~AA÷2mZoLWdG¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.57¬YA÷1.55¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.78¬YB÷3.8¬MG÷0¬XC÷5.2¬YC÷5.05¬MG÷0¬~AA÷tvYkKjCM¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.08¬YA÷2.12¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.28¬YB÷3.1¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.38¬YC÷3.56¬MG÷0¬~AA÷dtmxscC6¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.33¬YA÷1.68¬MG÷0¬XB÷5.55¬YB÷4.4¬MG÷0¬XC÷6.2¬YC÷3.96¬MG÷0¬~AA÷EHsstHRC¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.05¬YA÷1.09¬MG÷0¬XB÷11¬YB÷9.4¬MG÷0¬XC÷28¬YC÷19¬MG÷0¬~AA÷h8touysJ¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.98¬YA÷2.25¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.14¬YB÷4.5¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.99¬YC÷2.4¬MG÷0¬~AA÷4pghmYYu¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.65¬YA÷2¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.4¬YB÷4.04¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.9¬YC÷3.06¬MG÷0¬~AA÷2VBenhln¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.33¬YA÷3.01¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.2¬YB÷4.1¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.32¬YC÷2¬MG÷0¬~AA÷hK48qjY4¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.92¬YA÷2.3¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.4¬YB÷3.8¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.93¬YC÷2.48¬MG÷0¬~AA÷hWdSPA58¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.26¬YA÷2.07¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.54¬YB÷3.05¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.1¬YC÷3.8¬MG÷0¬~AA÷4duCpQn5¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.46¬YA÷1.46¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.1¬YB÷4.1¬MG÷0¬XC÷6.9¬YC÷6.9¬MG÷0¬~AA÷b3fG8tTH¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.46¬YA÷1.47¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.3¬YB÷4.7¬MG÷0¬XC÷5.8¬YC÷5.6¬MG÷0¬~AA÷tSqL70rO¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.92¬YA÷1.41¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.06¬YB÷4.8¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.84¬YC÷6.4¬MG÷0¬~AA÷KIrP6KcU¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.1¬YA÷1.22¬MG÷0¬XB÷7.3¬YB÷6.4¬MG÷0¬XC÷22¬YC÷9.9¬MG÷0¬~AA÷WjPUR3Tu¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.01¬YA÷1.03¬MG÷0¬XB÷19¬YB÷12¬MG÷0¬XC÷65¬YC÷49¬MG÷0¬XX÷XA|XB|XC¬~AA÷AsOYQNrn¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.46¬YA÷1.67¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.5¬YB÷4¬MG÷0¬XC÷5.5¬YC÷4.46¬MG÷0¬~AA÷fsEMH5cF¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷6.85¬YA÷5.4¬MG÷0¬XB÷5.25¬YB÷4.4¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.12¬YC÷1.47¬MG÷0¬~AA÷YXCQGPCL¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.03¬YA÷1.03¬MG÷0¬XB÷13¬YB÷9.6¬MG÷0¬XC÷49¬YC÷67¬MG÷0¬XX÷XA|XB|XC¬~AA÷fHOpYLrs¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.59¬YA÷2.55¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.42¬YB÷2.8¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.6¬YC÷2.85¬MG÷0¬~AA÷Y7NlXubm¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷4.68¬YA÷5.6¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.24¬YB÷3.5¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.8¬YC÷1.59¬MG÷0¬~AA÷SUMhWaDg¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.94¬YA÷2.2¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.06¬YB÷3.1¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.26¬YC÷3.16¬MG÷0¬~AA÷v5QdVJSa¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.34¬YA÷2.13¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.85¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.36¬YC÷3.44¬MG÷0¬~AA÷MTF1Uwr6¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.65¬YA÷2.33¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.56¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.24¬YC÷3.05¬MG÷0¬~AA÷xtGmlVBG¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷4.48¬YA÷3.66¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.66¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.71¬YC÷2.06¬MG÷0¬~AA÷8dnbPovG¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷4.64¬YA÷4.46¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.4¬YB÷2.9¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.75¬YC÷1.92¬MG÷0¬~AA÷GCr9sjhg¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.62¬YA÷1.89¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.62¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷5.3¬YC÷4.36¬MG÷0¬~AA÷pnmDtA7a¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.47¬YA÷2.47¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.8¬YB÷2.8¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.05¬YC÷3.05¬MG÷0¬~AA÷OxnHuUM5¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.43¬YA÷1.43¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.24¬YB÷4.24¬MG÷0¬XC÷6.8¬YC÷6.8¬MG÷0¬~AA÷ERvUxS6O¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.92¬YA÷1.92¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.85¬YB÷2.85¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.56¬YC÷4.56¬MG÷0¬~AA÷hIwYynMU¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.12¬YA÷2.12¬MG÷0¬XB÷3¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.46¬YC÷3.46¬MG÷0¬~AA÷IeJUtvJu¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.83¬YA÷1.88¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.34¬YB÷3.2¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.26¬YC÷4.04¬MG÷0¬~AA÷dnIYubYo¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.08¬YA÷2.08¬MG÷0¬XB÷3¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.56¬YC÷3.56¬MG÷0¬~AA÷j9HxuImh¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷5.5¬YA÷5.5¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.7¬YB÷3.7¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.57¬YC÷1.57¬MG÷0¬~AA÷lxcR2D4t¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷7.8¬YA÷7.4¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.1¬YB÷3.6¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.41¬YC÷1.48¬MG÷0¬~AA÷tKumh4v8¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.32¬YA÷2.32¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.9¬YB÷2.9¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.16¬YC÷3.16¬MG÷0¬~AA÷E7MugSv8¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.54¬YA÷3.54¬MG÷0¬XB÷3¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.1¬YC÷2.1¬MG÷0¬~AA÷hbLqhnfE¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.64¬YA÷3.64¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.9¬YB÷2.9¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.12¬YC÷2.12¬MG÷0¬~AA÷nLKmi69K¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3¬YA÷4.34¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.62¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.65¬YC÷1.9¬MG÷0¬~AA÷0OOijQOQ¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.34¬YA÷3.34¬MG÷0¬XB÷3¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.2¬YC÷2.2¬MG÷0¬~AA÷pd0Op4nl¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.65¬YA÷1.65¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.5¬YB÷3.5¬MG÷0¬XC÷5¬YC÷5¬MG÷0¬~AA÷vNovRf6c¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.49¬YA÷2.55¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.12¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.74¬YC÷2.65¬MG÷0¬~AA÷UBviOhjG¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷4.7¬YA÷5.2¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.38¬YB÷3.2¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.75¬YC÷1.71¬MG÷0¬~AA÷82weNC5M¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.18¬YA÷1.17¬MG÷0¬XB÷6.05¬YB÷6¬MG÷0¬XC÷13.5¬YC÷14.5¬MG÷0¬~AA÷I5b3TwJK¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.34¬YA÷2.36¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.24¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.9¬YC÷3.04¬MG÷0¬~AA÷2wzzOHtr¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.33¬YA÷2.37¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.13¬YB÷2.85¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.02¬YC÷3.15¬MG÷0¬~AA÷YyioLFQ0¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.3¬YA÷3.64¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.12¬YB÷2.9¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.18¬YC÷2.12¬MG÷0¬~AA÷jDojKZu7¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.15¬YA÷3.15¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.85¬YB÷2.85¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.37¬YC÷2.37¬MG÷0¬~AA÷U3pfJgeD¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.94¬YA÷2.94¬MG÷0¬XB÷3¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.42¬YC÷2.42¬MG÷0¬~AA÷x67cmgWj¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.66¬YA÷1.5¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.86¬YB÷4.3¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.52¬YC÷5.65¬MG÷0¬~AA÷j9euCx9i¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷7.7¬YA÷7.4¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.84¬YB÷5.2¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.34¬YC÷1.34¬MG÷0¬~AA÷lfErBdOc¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.42¬YA÷3.6¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.64¬YB÷3.7¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.95¬YC÷1.75¬MG÷0¬~AA÷CnbM1rx9¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.71¬YA÷1.61¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.52¬YB÷3.6¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.72¬YC÷5.2¬MG÷0¬~AA÷p0dUaM6L¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷4.52¬YA÷2.28¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.52¬YB÷3.5¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.74¬YC÷2.65¬MG÷0¬~AA÷2yiZbtMR¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.84¬YA÷1.8¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.1¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.44¬YC÷4.14¬MG÷0¬~AA÷Ast9hvae¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.99¬YA÷3.04¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.16¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.33¬YC÷2.35¬MG÷0¬~AA÷h6VDibE1¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.78¬YA÷1.83¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.44¬YB÷3.2¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.4¬YC÷4.26¬MG÷0¬~AA÷GKAYE2cS¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.68¬YA÷3.62¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.72¬YB÷3.78¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.85¬YC÷1.85¬MG÷0¬~AA÷dEh1AM5q¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.05¬YA÷2.37¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.5¬YB÷3.44¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.14¬YC÷2.77¬MG÷0¬~AA÷z5i59tLk¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.19¬YA÷2.25¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.5¬YB÷3.44¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.97¬YC÷2.9¬MG÷0¬~AA÷URj980zd¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.63¬YA÷1.82¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.04¬YB÷3.84¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.54¬YC÷3.7¬MG÷0¬~AA÷UHmeW3S2¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.95¬YA÷1.8¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.6¬YB÷3.9¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.46¬YC÷3.78¬MG÷0¬~AA÷GYk7T1CL¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.21¬YA÷1.19¬MG÷0¬XB÷6.15¬YB÷6.5¬MG÷0¬XC÷11¬YC÷12¬MG÷0¬~AA÷0OxyzIuo¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.71¬YA÷2.12¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.1¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷5.4¬YC÷3.46¬MG÷0¬~AA÷z991zBUC¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.17¬YA÷3.22¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.1¬YB÷3.1¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.29¬YC÷2.27¬MG÷0¬~AA÷Ea85ZUqJ¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.93¬YA÷2.02¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.28¬YB÷3.2¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.92¬YC÷3.66¬MG÷0¬~AA÷G4nlbEMJ¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.42¬YA÷3.03¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.97¬YB÷2.95¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.24¬YC÷2.47¬MG÷0¬~AA÷nmwKhhps¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.56¬YA÷2.6¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.2¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.63¬YC÷2.75¬MG÷0¬~AA÷QwxOiCam¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.56¬YA÷2.42¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.1¬YB÷3.15¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.73¬YC÷2.88¬MG÷0¬~AA÷6kgLjWEg¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.82¬YA÷2.05¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.34¬YB÷3.3¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.42¬YC÷3.5¬MG÷0¬~AA÷pthPkjUa¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.98¬YA÷1.87¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.3¬YB÷3.44¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.72¬YC÷4¬MG÷0¬~AA÷v3iTlAq6¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.38¬YA÷1.46¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.34¬YB÷4.04¬MG÷0¬XC÷8.3¬YC÷7¬MG÷0¬~AA÷h6eXmUbC¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.75¬YA÷1.67¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.44¬YB÷3.64¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.68¬YC÷5.05¬MG÷0¬~AA÷8WdNID6K¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷4.74¬YA÷4.74¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.3¬YB÷3.3¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.74¬YC÷1.74¬MG÷0¬~AA÷KAxbCBql¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.12¬YA÷2.12¬MG÷0¬XB÷3¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.46¬YC÷3.46¬MG÷0¬~AA÷b1y2BVbf¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.56¬YA÷3.54¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.85¬YB÷2.85¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.18¬YC÷2.18¬MG÷0¬~AA÷GYDzLG0f¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.4¬YA÷1.4¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.2¬YB÷4.2¬MG÷0¬XC÷7.3¬YC÷7.3¬MG÷0¬~AA÷bc3uKzG0¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.26¬YA÷3.24¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.88¬YB÷2.9¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.29¬YC÷2.28¬MG÷0¬~AA÷AX6qJfV6¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.72¬YA÷1.72¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.4¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.64¬YC÷4.64¬MG÷0¬~AA÷Czlh1nOh¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.43¬YA÷1.99¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.9¬YB÷3.3¬MG÷0¬XC÷8¬YC÷3.7¬MG÷0¬~AA÷4r6aaQh5¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.57¬YA÷1.54¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.78¬YB÷3.7¬MG÷0¬XC÷5.6¬YC÷6.4¬MG÷0¬~AA÷n7e4bp8B¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.86¬YA÷1.77¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.32¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.16¬YC÷4.68¬MG÷0¬~AA÷h6Nytxhp¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.96¬YA÷2.04¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.22¬YB÷3.3¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.84¬YC÷3.52¬MG÷0¬~AA÷WdMuud7j¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.9¬YA÷4.3¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.32¬YB÷3.2¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.91¬YC÷1.87¬MG÷0¬~AA÷n54S2aac¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.9¬YA÷1.77¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.16¬YB÷3.4¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.22¬YC÷4.76¬MG÷0¬~AA÷tS3W1JE3¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.74¬YA÷2.02¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.48¬YB÷3.24¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.56¬YC÷3.7¬MG÷0¬~AA÷0QBxQUj1¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.94¬YA÷2.07¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.24¬YB÷2.85¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.86¬YC÷3.86¬MG÷0¬~AA÷SW3OmYr8¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.16¬YA÷2.16¬MG÷0¬XB÷3¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.44¬YC÷3.44¬MG÷0¬~AA÷lnhXoCDK¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.18¬YA÷2.18¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.85¬YB÷2.85¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.54¬YC÷3.54¬MG÷0¬~AA÷nXAzoWSQ¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.56¬YA÷2.75¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.02¬YB÷2.9¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.74¬YC÷2.55¬MG÷0¬~AA÷raQQqN4H¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.38¬YA÷2.42¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.04¬YB÷2.65¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.02¬YC÷3.34¬MG÷0¬~AA÷hYF0wLso¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.09¬YA÷2.19¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.92¬YB÷2.6¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.84¬YC÷4.06¬MG÷0¬~AA÷23ci0rkb¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.9¬YA÷1.77¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.34¬YB÷3.1¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.92¬YC÷4.94¬MG÷0¬~AA÷z7QyHcBC¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.7¬YA÷2.65¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.1¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.54¬YC÷2.6¬MG÷0¬~AA÷vTCm5tNM¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷4.46¬YA÷4.66¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.9¬YB÷3.2¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.92¬YC÷1.77¬MG÷0¬~AA÷hzgObv0j¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷3.13¬YA÷3.15¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.13¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷2.27¬YC÷2.27¬MG÷0¬~AA÷6wcScbFd¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.01¬YA÷2.12¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.15¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.76¬YC÷3.54¬MG÷0¬~AA÷ABN86jJd¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.92¬YA÷2.6¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.2¬YB÷2.85¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.06¬YC÷2.75¬MG÷0¬~AA÷nmyCRLrU¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.24¬YA÷2.47¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.14¬YB÷2.9¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.17¬YC÷2.95¬MG÷0¬~AA÷bR4Uq3bb¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.28¬YA÷2.28¬MG÷0¬XB÷2.85¬YB÷2.85¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.34¬YC÷3.34¬MG÷0¬~AA÷6i8xrsTA¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷2.31¬YA÷2.7¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.06¬YB÷2.8¬MG÷0¬XC÷3.12¬YC÷2.7¬MG÷0¬~AA÷pr7ts1rH¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.78¬YA÷2.09¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.46¬YB÷3¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.36¬YC÷3.56¬MG÷0¬~AA÷beMCRrzb¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.72¬YA÷2.02¬MG÷0¬XB÷3.8¬YB÷3.6¬MG÷0¬XC÷4.04¬YC÷3.06¬MG÷0¬~AA÷bVvFwm1M¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷7.1¬YA÷7.1¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.5¬YB÷4.5¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.37¬YC÷1.37¬MG÷0¬~AA÷OtApPTPN¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷6.5¬YA÷3.84¬MG÷0¬XB÷4¬YB÷3.2¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.46¬YC÷1.92¬MG÷0¬~AA÷W69lOmuU¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷1.33¬YA÷1.77¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.42¬YB÷3.6¬MG÷0¬XC÷9.1¬YC÷4.2¬MG÷0¬~AA÷zLZbriQo¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷9.8¬YA÷5¬MG÷0¬XB÷4.52¬YB÷3.6¬MG÷0¬XC÷1.31¬YC÷1.63¬MG÷0¬~AA÷CUQwsW
```

Here is also the cURL code used:

```
curl 'https://d.flashscore.com.br/x/feed/fo_1_0_-3_pt-br_1_0' \
  -H 'authority: d.flashscore.com.br' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="99"' \
  -H 'accept-language: *' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36 Edg/99.0.1150.30' \
  -H 'x-fsign: SW9D1eZo' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -H 'x-referer: https://www.flashscore.com.br/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://d.flashscore.com.br/x/feed/proxy-local' \
  -H 'cookie: (I wont put cookies here for security reasons)...' \
  --compressed
```

And here the header response:

```
Server: nginx
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Vary: accept-encoding
X-Expired-Cache: 1
X-Signature: 66b5c2f18efbf6d995bbe2fbba28bce5
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-grace-enabled: 1
Cache-Control: private,no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
X-Vname: lsproxy-7645cc46d8-wsvph/varnish1[P]|lsbproxy-6978cfdcfb-c2fkv/varnish1[A]|lsproxy33/varnish1[P]|lsbproxy8/varnish2[A]
X-ttlSet: BEH[P]|BEH[A]|BEH[P]|BEH[A]
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sat, 05 Mar 2022 16:18:46 GMT
Age: 1
X-times: 1646497126156|1646497126157
X-Age: 1[P]|1[A]|0[P]|0[A]
X-PC: MISS[P]|HIT[A]|MISS[P]|MISS[A]
X-Geoip2-Country-Code: US
X-Geoip2-City-Name: North Bergen
X-Geoip2-Subdivision-Name-0: New Jersey
X-Geoip2-Subdivision-Code-0: NJ
X-Geoip2-ISO-Subdivision-Code-0: US-NJ
Via: 1.1 google
Alt-Svc: clear
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Something I also noticed, is that the answer always ends with `¬~`.

I was wondering what kind of answer this is, if it's an answer in some format, or is it encoded (if so, I have access to the platform's javascript, I can try to decode it). I also thought it was maybe some kind of xls worksheet, but with no result.

Comment: *Even intercepting the platform, it ALSO receives the same "encoded" response without using cURL* - Yes, simply opening the web page shows a request of `mc_1` in that format, originating from some JS code. But reverse engineering arbitrary code is off topic here. People at https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ might help you with ideas about where/what to look, but at the end probably you will have to walk through that `modules.xyz.js`

Comment: that's what I thought, really the answer is not compressed, and what would this ```mc_1``` and this ```module.xyz.js``` be?

Answer (score -2):

I believe the response is `gzip` encoded/compressed [1], and you need to decompress it. Try piping the body of the response into `gunzip` on linux.

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding

Comment: `--compressed` handles that part.

Comment: I'm already using